# Microsoft Graph API doesn't return the properties I need

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to do a simple query using ms graph API to get the user's `aboutMe` property:

```
    string filter = @"
startswith(displayName,'Bassie')
";

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .Select("aboutMe")
    .GetAsync();
```

But I just keep getting

> {Code: NotImplementedMessage: This operation target is not yet supported. Inner error}

Where the InnerError doesn't contain any useful information.

It works fine when I do the same with `mail`.

Why is this? I'm fairly sure I have retrieved `aboutMe` section using graph API before, but I don't remember exaclty how...

When trying it with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select('AboutMe')
```

It returns objects like this

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?=%24select(%27AboutMe%27)&$skiptoken=X%2744537074020001000000273A24504A424632302D344D474E324C34484551384E40776F726C6579706172736F6E732E636F6D29557365725F62363964646464302D353865332D343537332D386639332D363033333731386231336237B900000000000000000000%27",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "d6a2b540-bd56-420f-bb46-bb46d6a2b540",
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "54-3-24",
        "givenName": "user",
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": "user@domain.com",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": "surname",
        "userPrincipalName": "username@domain.com"
    }
```

What does this mean? How am I supposed to retrieve the properties that I need? And if only some are available, is there a reference for this? I don't want to have to test out every single property before I know which are available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `aboutMe` property of `user` entity could not be retrieved for a *collection of users*, only for a single user (entity) it is supported to retrieve this property like this:

```
/beta/users/me?$select=aboutMe
```

> Refer [this thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/381) that lists all the properties that could not be
>   retrieved per user collection.

The query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select('AboutMe')
```

is invalid and in your case select query option expression is simply ignored since it is provided incorrectly, here is the example how to specify `select` query option (follow [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select-parameter) for a more details):

```
/beta/users?$select=email,displayName
```

Answer (score 1):

> /v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Bassie')&$select('AboutMe')

will execute properly but, the c# sdk will resolve your Queries to the following format

> /v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Bassie')&$select=AboutMe

["BaseRequest.cs, ~line 310"](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/BaseRequest.cs)

However select

> /v1.0/users?$select=AboutMe

seems to throw the NotImplementedException.

Not sure if this is a bug, but i would recommend you to submit a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues)